# Adding points or hover tips from CSV file

Tags: qgis

I am using 
QGIS version
3.4.1-Madeira
and want to add either a point on a map or hovertips on data that is in the attribute table.

What is the best method to do this?

Comment: turn on Map Tips for that layer and configure what you want to show in the properties of the layer under Display

Comment: _Add a point on a map_ ? What do you mean ? What do u want to do that qgis is not already **naturally** doing ?

Answer (score 1):

**If your CSV file has geospatial information in it**

Geospatial information should be two separate columns, called something like X coordinate and Y coordinate, or Latitude and Longitude.

[Import the CSV](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html) using `Add Delimited Text layer` in the Layer menu > Add layer. This will add points to your map, and each point will be associated with the data from the same row of the CSV.

**If your CSV file doesn't have geospatial information**:

1. Create a new point layer.
2. Add new point features until you have one for each row of the CSV.
3. Assign a unique ID to each point feature that corresponds to a unique ID already in the CSV. If the CSV doesn't have a unique ID field, add one.
4. Import the CSV as an attribute-only table.
5. Do a [table join](https://www.gislounge.com/working-with-tables-mastering-qgis/) between the CSV and the point layer you created.

Once you have the CSV data in your QGIS project and associated with points on the map canvas, do as DPSSpatial said:

> Turn on Map Tips for that layer and configure what you want to show in the properties of the layer under Display.